# use the same README content in sphinx and github - relative links

Tags: python, github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm adding a Read The Docs page for my project. For now, I want the same content on my Read The Docs homepage as in my README. My `docs/index.rst` file looks like:

```
.. include:: ../README.rst

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

This mostly works, except for relative links. For example, my README contains:

```
See `INSTALL.rst`_ for advanced and detailed instructions.
```

Since Sphinx builds everything within the docs directory, it is expecting to find `INSTALL.rst` inside the docs directory.

Since Github renders the file from root, it expects to find `INSTALL.rst` in the root directory.

How can I make Github and Read The Docs (Sphinx) both render relative links correctly without having duplicate files (or preferably, any duplication)?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the symboric link.

In the sphinx directory:

```
INSTALL.rst -> ../INSTALL.rst
```